# What is the retry interval for Apache once it has hit it's max connections?

Tags: apache, max, connection

If Apache reaches it's max number of connections, or it's max clients, how long will it wait, before trying again to connect any of the connections that couldn't connect?  Or will it just drop the connection the first time and never try again?  If it does wait, is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache will simply queue connections into its ListenBackLog. Then once a current connection is done, Apache will attempt to serve the oldest queued connection.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listenbacklog

I think the TimeOut Directive does effect what happens with a connection in the ListenBackLog queue.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

If its been the timeout limit since a connection was queued, that connection is dropped.